# getting records from 2 tables and merge them by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Lets say I have 2 tables in my database, both have 'updated_at' field.
I want to retrieve all the records in both tables in one active record query.
I should return one large activerecord relation ordered by updated_at field.
Let assume these two tables are really similar.

If it is possible, it would be better to have the ability to only return the first 50, or second 50, or so on.

here's an example

```
cats = Cat.all
dog = Dog.all

animals = (cats | dogs).sort!{|a,b| a.updated_at <=> b.updated_at}.limit(50)
```

It is pretty costly to get all dogs then cats then merge them into one, and then get the first 50 animals.

I need a way to make one query to db and the db returns the first 50 animals.
or the second 50 animals.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? It would also be nice to have a better understanding of the tables you are referencing.

Answer (score 2):

Given that these models are so similar, wouldn't be better to use ActiveRecord's [Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)? For the example you provided, you would have base class Animal, and you would get the results you want with just Animal.order("updated_at").limit(50)

Comment: Agree with this. Have one table .. use the type column as per STI to specify the class each record responds to.

Comment: nope, that was just an example. it could be Cat and Airplane,

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single query, but an obvious optimization would be to only grab the first 50 of each instead of the whole tables:

```
cats = Cat.order_by(:updated_at).limit(50)
dogs = Dog.order_by(:updated_at).limit(50)

animals = (cats + dogs).sort_by(&:updated_at).first(50)
```

You could then get the next 50 by querying on the last `updated_at`

```
last_animal_date = animals.last.updated_a
next_cats = Cat.where("updated_at > ?", last_date).order_by(:updated_at).limit(50)
next_dogs = Dog.where("updated_at > ?", last_date).order_by(:updated_at).limit(50)
# etc ...
```

Clearly with the amount of repetition this needs to be factored into a method but I leave that as an exercise to the reader :)